# China greyed out in play store developer console?

Tags: android, google-play

In the 'pricing and disbtirubtion' window of my Play Store console some countries are greyed out including China which I really want to get into. What do I need to do to have access to that store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of Android devices you bought in China came with variety of KIRF store app which is full of pirate and cracked app, some even replace the default Google Play Store (what the hell ???!!!).

What even worse is most of google service (of cause Google Play Store is no doubt on the blacklist) are censored and intermittently blocked by the government.

It is indeed a very very big and emerging markets, but it is an nightmare for creator (perhaps too big to break in ???), so forget about it and don't waste your time.

BTW, if you write free app, you can submit it via these KIRF store app, actually you even don't need do that, most of free app in Google play will be taken care and available in these KIRF store app sooner or later (Don't worry, they will do it for you for free). If you plan to write paid app...

[image]

Comment: What about in-app billing? Is it even works in China? Is there same problems as with paid apps?